# How get value from URL

Tags: php, url

I want to get the value from the URL to choose data from the database by ID. I want the value for the id.

For example, if I were to open `www.example.com/index.php?id=12`.
I want to get a value whose id = 12 in the database.

If I open `www.example.com/index.php?id=7`.

I want to get the value whose id = 7 in the database and so on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Website URL:

```
http://www.example.com/?id=2
```

Code:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to get variable from URL in PHP:

When your URL is: `http://www.example.com/index.php?id=7` you can get this `id` via `$_GET['id']` or `$_REQUEST['id']` command and store in `$id` variable.

**Lest's take a look:**

```
// url is www.example.com?id=7

//get id from url via $_GET['id'] command:
$id = $_GET['id']
```

**same will be:**

```
//get id from url via $_REQUEST['id'] command:
$id = $_REQUEST['id']
```

the difference is that variables can be passed to file via URL or via **POST** method.

if variable is passed through url, then you can get it with `$_GET['variable_name']` or `$_REQUEST['variable_name']` but if variable is posted, then you need to you `$_POST['variable_name']` or `$_REQUEST['variable_name']`

So as you see `$_REQUEST['variable_name']` can be used in both ways.

Comment: You still have `$_GET` at your `$_REQUEST` example. Also, if you want to get `GET` data,  you should use `$_GET`. This implies that you  should never use `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @djot agree with you about `GET`. Yes it's always better to use exact method for caching variable, but I just wrote for understanding for @Vaja how variables are sent to file and how they can be cached.

Comment: thanks to all sorry I can't rate all of you but witch was more simple and first thump up it 

thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You can get that value by using the `$_GET` array. So the id value would be stored in `$_GET['id']`.

So in your case you could store that value in the `$id` variable as follows:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: This didnt work for me. I dont know why but the variable got empty... :|

Answer (score 1):

You can access those values with the global $_GET variable

```
//www.example.com/index.php?id=7
print $_GET['id']; // prints "7"
```

You should check all "incoming" user data - so here, that "id" is an INT. Don't use it directly in your SQL (vulnerable to SQL injections).

Comment: thanks to all sorry I can't rate all of you but witch was more simple and first thump up it 

thank you all

Comment: I was first ... ok, second ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a query string value as:

```
$uri =  $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; //it will print full url
$uriArray = explode('/', $uri); //convert string into array with explode
$id = $uriArray[1]; //Print first array value
```